# Is there RESTful webservice calls avaible in WSUS

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008, windows-update

I want to know details of an update from a remote WSUS server through RESTFul or any other Webservice call, Is that possible. I'm aware of `Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration` and it's usage.

Comment: Please read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn about [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You can definitely use Windows Update Agent API for client systems to pull updates from WSUS Server! The WSUS API is also available for use if you want to perform some action on the WSUS Server itself. If you only want updates to be pulled from WSUS, you should check WIndows Update Agent API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wua_sdk/portal-client

Comment: Thanks @Am_I_Helpful for the response, My idea is to export metadata information about all the updates available in a particular WSUS Server.

Comment: @AlenNishabu - It seems you should go with the WSUS API then to fetch update information from the server. Please let me know if you need any further help.

Comment: Thanks again @Am_I_Helpful, I would like to have a sample usage of WSUS SOAP. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn689324.aspx

Comment: @AlenNishabu - Sorry for the late reply! I don't have experience of web-services in WSUS, and there is lack of documents too. I'd suggest you to look WSUS API if it is possible for you. Is there a requirement of yours to use Web Services only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESTful web services are not supported by WSUS Administration API.
SOAP has to be used to communicate with the server. There are many open source SOAP client appliations which can be used for this task.
Remember about the authentication mechanism which developing the solution.
I used Python3 requests, ntlm and zeep libraries to achieve this task.