# How to connect to WSUS server using WSUS remote API from a web API?

Tags: windows-update

I am trying to connect to WSUS server remotely from my web application built in ASP.NET Core 2.0. I am using the Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.dll to achieve this. I was  able to establish successful connection to the server when I built a C# console application and used the same dll file in assembly reference.
I have referred to these similar posts but I have not found an answer yet.
- [Is there RESTful webservice calls avaible in WSUS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52418274/is-there-restful-webservice-calls-avaible-in-wsus#)
- [How to make a SOAP call to WSUS Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52695482/how-to-make-a-soap-call-to-wsus-server)

[I am sorry for not maintaining indentation and proper formatting in the sample code.]

Below is the sample code from the console app which worked:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration;

namespace WsusRemoteConnectivityConsoleApp
{
  class Program
  {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         IUpdateServer remoteServer = 
         AdminProxy.GetUpdateServer("WsusServer1",false,8530);
         Console.WriteLine(remoteServer.Name);
      }
  }
}
```

The expected output as well as the actual output in the console app is "WsusServer1".
But using the same line of code in the web app, I am not able to connect to the WSUS server. I receive exception saying that "The requested security protocol is not supported" in this line 
IUpdateServer remoteServer = 
                 AdminProxy.GetUpdateServer("WsusServer1",false,8530);

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Check after adding this line `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;` in your Global.asax file! Not much information has been shared by you related to OS Version, SSL settings modified recently, etc.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful Firstly, Global.asax file has been removed in .Net Core 2.0. So I tried adding your code in Startup.cs file but the issue is still there. Secondly, WSUS 3.0 is installed on Windows Server 2012 R2 with SSL enabled using a self-signed cert. 
My question is: Can i establish remote connection to the WSUS server by just adding references to the WSUS API assemblies and not having WSUS 3.0 installed on my client?

Comment: _Correction_ WSUS version is 6.3.9600.18838

Answer (score 0):

if you have setup SSL, you should use:

```
AdminProxy.GetUpdateServer("WsusServer1",true,8531);
```